# Reference root view from UI element?

Tags: swift

If I have any `UI element`, in this case the description UIlabel

[image]

I know that doing:

```
description.superView
```

will reference to DescriptionContainerView, but

**Is it possible to reference the root view? from these element**,

Note: I don't want to use `self.view` because I want to reference this from another context where self variable is not what you expect

Comment: `self.superView.superView....superView`, but that's not recommended. What about using a closure or a delegate to allow your button (or rather its owner) to tell your UIViewController to do something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like this way(This is not the good approach):

```
description.superView.superView.superView
```

You can add recursive function like that:

```
func getSuperView(mainView: Any) -> UIView? {
        if let view = mainView as? UIView, view.tag == 1001 {
            return view
        } else {
           return getSuperView(mainView: mainView)
        }
    }
```

Comment: this will work, but I want to create a dinamyc function where I don't know how many views are nested..

Comment: Then give a tag to Your targeted view(main view) and call the recursive function till not getting this tag

Comment: @RenzoCalla: Please check my updated answer, I have added recursive function to get super view

Answer (score 1):

You can create extension for UIView with recursive function and check that current superview is not UIWindow.

```
extension UIView {
   func getRootSuperView() -> UIView {
        if let superview = self.superview, !(superview is UIWindow) {
            return superview.getRootSuperView()
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```